# Run unit test for main and specific flavours android

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin, android-sourcesets

I have 5 Flavors mapped to 2 source folders with some common code written in main folder, The b folder has some extra beans for which I have written unit test, now I want to run unit test like all the unit tests in main folders run with some specific unit test written for B app.

1.Where should I place the folder specific unit test for B app. I have trued creating a folder test and placing those test in that folder and adding

`unitTest {
            java.srcDir file('src/b/test')
        }`

in the source set of B app but not this is not working
2.How should I place mapping for unit tests, these are not android tests, I already tired [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673395/how-to-run-unit-tests-with-dependency-to-an-android-library-module) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154115/create-separate-test-module-project-in-android-studio) but these seems to be for Android Test not for unit test.

```
productFlavors {
        staging {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".test"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "A Test"
            //other keys
        }
        prod {
            resValue "string", "app_name", "A"
            //other keys
        }
        dev {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".dev"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "A Dev"
            //other keys
        }

        BStaging {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".b.test"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "B Test"
         //other keys
        }

        BProd {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".b"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "B"
      //other keys
        }
    }

sourceSets {
        prod {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/a/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/a/res']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/a/java']
            manifest.srcFile 'src/a/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        dev {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/a/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/a/res']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/a/java']
            manifest.srcFile 'src/a/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        staging {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/a/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/a/res']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/a/java']
            manifest.srcFile 'src/a/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        BStaging {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/b/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/b/res']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/b/java']
            manifest.srcFile 'src/b/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        BProd {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/b/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/b/res']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/b/java']
            manifest.srcFile 'src/b/AndroidManifest.xml'

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey man I have not used source set, but I was able to run flavour based test using this command pattern. (Without quotes) "./gradlew test<ProductFlavour><BuildType>UnitTest".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your **product flavour** and **build type** created like this.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        develop {

        }

        production {

        }
    }
```

You can run flavour based test using this command in your studio terminal.

- For **develop** flavour and **debug** build : **./gradlew testDevelopDebugUnitTest**
- For **develop** flavour and **release** build : **./gradlew testDevelopReleaseUnitTest**

So the pattern goes like **test<*Flavour*><*BuildType*>UnitTest**

Answer (score 0):

Running `./gradlew tasks` will show you list of all tasks you can run for all combinations of your build types and flavors.
Scroll down to find the tasks related to tests.